# PHP capture word that contains special char from string using RegEx

Tags: php, regex

I have special words in a string that i would like to capture based on the prefix.
**Example**  `Special words such as ^to_this should be caught`.
I would need the word `this` because of the special prefix `^to_`.
Here is my attempt but it is not working

```
preg_match('/\b(\w*^to_\w*)\b/', $str, $specialWordArr);
```

but this returns an empty array

Comment: i would need to pull the word `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = 'Special words such as ^to_this should be caught';
$regex = '~[_^;]\w+[_^;](\w+)~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[1]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?>  //=> this
```

**Explanation:**

- `[_^;]` Add the special characters into this character class to ensure that the begining of a word would be a special character.
- `\w+` After a special character, there must  one or more word characters  followed.
- `[_^;]` Word characters must be followed by  a special character.
- `(\w+)` If these conditions are satisfied, capture the following one or more word characters into a group.

Answer (score 1):

Without some additional examples this will work for what you've posted:

```
$str = 'Special words such as ^to_this should be caught';   

preg_match('/\s\^to_(\w+)\s/', $str, $specialWordArr);

echo $specialWordArr[1]; //this
```